# Use linker script to convert identifier from CamelCase to snake_case?

Tags: c, linker-scripts, camelcasing, snakecasing

i am working on a C project using a snake_case syntax for naming my functions.
However, a lib i need to uses CamelCase for all of its function names.

To avoid doing a long header full of static inline definitions, i wonder if i could be possible
to take advantage of linked script, to dynamically convert the objects identifiers from CamelCase to snake_case.

Is it possible?

Comment: What sources do you have? Do you have the foreign lib source or just a `.so`? In either case, you'll need a script to parse the source or symtab to get a list of translations to feed a linker script or a `.h`. Just function names or also global variables? Please edit your question and post some examples of input symbols and corresponding output symbols. Do you have individual `.c/.o` files?

Comment: I'm not sure that a _linker_ can change identifiers, but perhaps make pairs mean the same thing. Anyway, objcopy of GNU's binutils can redefine symbols. Please [edit] your question and tell us what target system, compiler, linker, and binary tools you use.

Comment: Using some consistent style for your own code is one thing. Trying to force that same style to third party code and libraries is a different thing. I would not suggest to mess around with those symbols and just use them as they are defined. That also helps distinguishing whether a function is from some external library or your own code